# Как подключить нужную Razor Library через DI?

Tags: asp.net, razor, dependency-injection

Уважаемые Гуру!
Есть главное окно - Index.razor. В нем необходимо отобразить карту, допустим так

```
<MapView  />
```

Component MapView может быть из разных JS библиотек, скажем MapBox или leaflet.
Сейчас я делаю так:

```
@if (sw == "mapbox")
{
    <MapboxView  />
}
else
{
    <LeafletView  />
}
```

Есть ли возможность подключать нужную библиотеку через Dependency Injection?
Т.е. в коде

```
<IMapView />
```

,
а откуда берется реализация интерфейса определять через DI?